# Express Node Request For Loop Issue

Tags: node.js, express

While running request in a loop it shows an error ETIMEOUT around 101 times (length of the array).

```
for(var x=0;x<100;x++){request({
  uri: "abc.com,
 qs: {
   "token": 'xyz',
 },
 timeout:10000,}, function (err, result) {});}
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: If you try to reach the url in the browser, do you get a timeout too?

Comment: Is that endpoint able to handle 100 concurrent connections?

Comment: In browser its working fine when i am calling the url manually. I am calling one url at a time in browser.
May be the endpoint is not able to handle 100 request at a time.
can it is possible to call next request when the response of first will come.

Comment: You should call them one at a time in node too. You don't want to launch a DOS-attack against abc.com, do you?

Comment: How can i call next request after receiving the response from last request.
Please give me an example.